# Does JVM keeps track of index in foreach loop in Java? If so, How?

Tags: java

I know it's not possible to get the index in foreach loop. Either we need to use normal loop or use an index which gets incremented/decremented in each iteration.

I have followed this question also.
[Java, How do I get current index/key in “for each” loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431529/java-how-do-i-get-current-index-key-in-for-each-loop).

I just want to know whether, Java keeps any index in each iteration. If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends.

There are two versions of this loop, for arrays and for `Iterable` (things like `List`).

For arrays, the compiler will create a "normal" `for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loop. So here you have that index.

For `Iterable`, it becomes `while(iter.hasMore()){`. So there is no index in the loop itself. Depending on the `Iterable` implementation, there may still be one inside the `Iterator`.

Comment: All the gory details in [§14.14.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Answer (score 0):

No designed way to know current index in foreach loop, it works not like

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
```

but like:

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already know that any instance of a class that implements `Iterable` interface can be used in the `foreach` loop. For any finite collection of objects, there is no way an `Iterator` can be implemented without doing some sort of house keeping (in most cases the index). So, in effect an index is stored somewhere, though it is not accessible to us.

Have a look at the `AbstractList` implementation of `iterator` method to see how it is implemented for lists.