# Iterate through a List until a specific String and say the Line Number?

Tags: java

Here's my list example:

```
List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
l2.add("Apple");
l2.add("Kiwi");
l2.add("Orange");
```

So Basically I want to iterate through this list until it finds for example "Orange" then it'll return a Line number (3 in this example). But I'm really not sure how to do this. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Your current expected output could simply be achieved using indexOf

Comment: It sounds a lot like a simple `List.indexOf(Object o) + 1`.  If your List is sorted, you could write a faster search, like a binary search

Comment: do you want to print the line number of the code or the index of "Orange" in your list? For line numbers, you can use `new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this while iterating over the list. Here's an example:

```
int i = 0;
for( String s : l2){
    if(s.equals("Orange")) System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: this will print the index of "Orange" in the List, not necessarily what line number `l2.add("Orange")` is on

Comment: I don't believe that is what the OP was asking for. If I am mistaken OP please correct me.

Comment: `foreach` is not a valid keyword, it's called a for-each loop but uses the same `for` keyword.  Also note that this is the wrong usage of a for-each loop, you should just use a normal for loop in this case

Comment: @peggy If OP was looking for *literal* program line number, the expected result would be four (or greater - once you include the class this code is in) rather than 3 as the OP provides

Comment: @DoubleDouble Or if your line numbers start at 0, it could be 3.  Except it seems to be clear that they meant in the List, not in the program

Comment: @DoubleDouble Ah yes you are correct. Sorry- I saw line number and thought line number... not index.

Comment: @phflack Sorry about the foreach, too much C# lately. And I don't believe it's correct to say it's the "wrong" usage for the for-each loop. The choice seems stylistic and should compile to comparable bytecode.

Comment: A for-each loop is designed to be clean and hide the iterator.  If you're going to use the index it is more common to instead use an indexed for loop instead.  [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3431543/5475891).  Overall, using the for-each loop implies you don't care about the index

Comment: @phflack It may be more common but either way is correct. I think the for-each looks prettier.

Comment: @phflack *"I think the for-each looks prettier"* lmao.

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop to iterate through any Array or list. In this case being an Array list you would iterate through it with the following for loop

```
for(int x = 0; x < l2.size();x++){
    if(l2.get(x).equals("Orange")){
      // this is where the code will end up when it selects Orange
    }
}
```

The `l2.size()` method gets the whole size of the ArrayList and x 1 is added to x each time it is smaller than the Arraylist size. The `if` statement will stop as soon as it finds the text in the ArrayList in the `equals` parameters, this is where you should put your code if you want to add, remove or do something at this point.

Comment: It is much easier to just use `List.indexOf(Object o)`.  In this case it would be `int index = l2.indexOf("Orange");`

Comment: Thanks i didnt know that.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and found a much easier way: 
int indexOf(Object o)
Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

Comment: @phflack actually provided this in a comment 10 minutes ago, but glad you figured it out regardless.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Made it an answer to make it easier to see. And I didn't see his comment.

Comment: @DoubleDouble actually luk2302 suggested it [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424485/iterate-through-a-list-until-a-specific-string-and-say-the-line-number#comment56590605_34424485).

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I do think whoever is downvoting the answer because "someone else first" is rather ridiculous, I more or less just wanted to point out that sometimes people should pay attention to the comments.. If they truly wanted to get answer-points they would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I mostly didn't provide it as an answer because I didn't feel it was enough to be an answer with the given question.  It was unclear what you were asking so it was unclear what the answer should be