# Augmented for loop in Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to use the augmented for loop to traverse through an array where the index is also required.

For example suppose I want to traverse an array of integers and add each number along with its index to a `Map`. My code will be something like

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++){
            map.put(numbers[i], i);
        }
```

Is there a way to write this using the `for-each` loop.

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of the one you've mentioned. I know how for-each loop works. The question is how can I access the index in a for-each loop?

Comment: In Java 8+ you could do `IntStream.of(0, numbers.length).forEach(i -> map.put(numbers[i], i));`

Comment: @Clockwork I agree. Here's a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431529/java-how-do-i-get-current-index-key-in-for-each-loop