# Android: how to get index of ArrayList row with custom object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexof

I'm having songs ArrayList like this

```
songs.add(new Songs("Rumour Has It","Adele", "Adele21", R.drawable.adele, 1991, R.drawable.adele21_cover));

songs.add(new Songs("Turning Tables","Adele", "Adele21", R.drawable.adele, 1991, R.drawable.adele21_cover));

songs.add(new Songs("dangerous","M Jackson", "Dangerous", R.drawable.jackson, 1992, R.drawable.dangerous_cover));
```

I want to get the index of ArrayList row which has the song "Turning Tables" which is now playing so I can play next or previous song

```
String songName = preferenceConfig.readSongName();
for(Songs s : MainActivity.songs){
    boolean resultOfComparison= songName.equals(s.getSong());
    if(resultOfComparison){
       //how to get the index of this row which contains this song
    }
 }
```

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431529/java-how-do-i-get-current-index-key-in-for-each-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Songs s : MainActivity.songs) {
     boolean resultOfComparison= songName.equals(s.getSong());
     if(resultOfComparison){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Current index is: " + (songIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     songIndex++;
}
```